# Solving derivative of $f(x) = x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ from definition

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this problem: $f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$. I am asked the find the derivative of $f$ from definition.
I know the means that we have to solve it with $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. But when I put in the numbers, I get $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^{\frac{2}{3}}-x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{h}$. I can't really simplify that. I tried using l'hopital's rule though that would find the derivative of $x^{\frac23}$ itself and would be kinda... cheating. Can someone help with this question?

Comment: Try binomial series

Comment: Is the generalized power rule for derivatives needed to derive the binomial series?  If so, using a binomial series to prove a power rule formula is circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, using L'Hôpital's rule here is circular reasoning.  You need to algebraically simplify the difference quotient so the denominator doesn't tend to zero anymore.

First, using the difference of squares formula:
$$
    (x+h)^{2/3} - x^{2/3} = \left((x+h)^{1/3} + x^{1/3}\right)\left((x+h)^{1/3} - x^{1/3}\right)
$$
Then, using the difference of *cubes* formula
$$
    A^3 - B^3 = (A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2)
$$
with $A = (x+h)^{1/3}$ and $B=x^{1/3}$, we have
$$
    \left((x+h)^{1/3} - x^{1/3}\right)
    = \frac{(x+h)-x}{(x+h)^{2/3} + (x+h)^{1/3}x^{1/3} + x^{2/3}}
$$
Can you put that all together and let $h \to 0$?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the difference of cubes formula 
$$a^3 - b^3 = (a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$$
with $a = (x + h)^{2/3}$ and $b = x^{2/3}$.

Given $f(x) = x^{2/3}$,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} & = \frac{(x + h)^{2/3} - x^{2/3}}{h}\\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x + h)^{2/3} - x^{2/3}}{h} \cdot \frac{(x + h)^{4/3} + (x + h)^{2/3}x^{2/3} + x^{4/3}}{(x + h)^{4/3} + (x + h)^{2/3}x^{2/3} + x^{4/3}}\\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x + h)^2 - x^2}{h[(x + h)^{4/3} + (x + h)^{2/3}x^{2/3} + x^{4/3}]}\\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x^2 + 2xh + h^2 - x^2}{h[(x + h)^{4/3} + (x + h)^{2/3}x^{2/3} + x^{4/3}]}\\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2xh + h^2}{h[(x + h)^{4/3} + (x + h)^{2/3}x^{2/3} + x^{4/3}]}
\end{align*}
Can you finish it from here?